# Mysql Order By Asc not ordering by first letter

Tags: mysql

i have some problem with Order By,i want to order by some field with the first letter,which is A,but i already make Order By ASC Query,but it start with Letter C instead of A. i have a screenshot result of my query.
[image]

Why does this happen ?

Comment: Because all records before the ones with `A` have a space at the beginning.

Comment: no,it doesnt have space at the beginning....@juergend

Comment: if it not contain space, it may contain special character which in invisible... pls check carefully

Comment: i already compared the data start from first Letter A,and C.the letter A has / special character,and C has ( special character.but there's not any invisible character between both of data @ShahadatHossainKhan

Comment: can you write a script and print ascii value of first letter of each record

Comment: i still havent learn to do that...@ShahadatHossainKhan

Comment: There *is* an invisible character before "Wheat Powder" (177), and there is *no* such character before "Abon Sapi..." (3). Fix the data (strongly recommended) or use ORDER BY LTRIM(nama_bahan).

Comment: it worked ! Thanks @Rahul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be leading spaces in your column `nama_bahan` values and thus try using `TRIM()` before ordering it like

```
order by trim(nama_bahan)
```